# Center text horizontally within flexbox using CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

I'm trying to make a navigation bar for a website. I'm attempting to center my link text horizontally within a div. `text-align: center;` isn't doing the trick, and neither are `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`. Any tips?

```css
#nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row rtl;
  border-top: 3px dotted #594027;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #594027;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbox {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #594027;
  width: 125px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbox a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<div class="navbox">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="navbox">
<a href="resume.html">Resumé</a>
</div>
<div class="navbox">
<a href="coursework.html">Coursework</a>
</div>
<div class="navbox">
<a href="accomplishments.html">Accomplishments</a>
</div>
<div class="navbox">
<a href="experience.html">Experience</a>
</div>
<div class="navbox">
<a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
</div>

</div><!--nav->
```

Comment: Add "text-align:center" to the .navbox class.

BTW, You don't need the "margin-right" & "margin-left" "auto".

Comment: Also, the "Flex-wrap" es for the "Flex container", not for the elements inside the flex container, so, remove it from your .navbox class.

Comment: What isn't as you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can controle text from parent , for that you will need to add `text-align:center` to `#nav`

```css
#nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row rtl;
  border-top: 3px dotted #594027;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #594027;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Add text-align to Parent */
  text-align:center;
}

.navbox {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #594027;
  width: 125px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbox a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<div class="navbox">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="navbox">
<a href="resume.html">Resumé</a>
</div>
<div class="navbox">
<a href="coursework.html">Coursework</a>
</div>
<div class="navbox">
<a href="accomplishments.html">Accomplishments</a>
</div>
<div class="navbox">
<a href="experience.html">Experience</a>
</div>
<div class="navbox">
<a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
</div>

</div><!--nav->
```